# How to start an application in android when mobile is switched ON?

Tags: android, restart, background-service

Hai i have a application using background service.its running clearly.If my mobile is switch off,my service is ound service off.when my application is started then only my background service is strated .i want to restart the service again when mobile switch off?
is it possible?
Anybody explain with code

**update**

```
public class loginForm extends Activity 
{
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView (R.layout.login);
receiver = new ConnectionReceiver();
 registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}
 }

private class ConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        private Timer mTimer;
        private TimerTask mTimerTask;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra         (ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

                if(null != info)
                {
                        String state = getNetworkStateString(info.getState());
                        if(state.equals("Connected")){
                            mTimer = new Timer();
                            mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    loginForm.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {

                                            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Disenabled provider " + provider,
                                                    ///Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                                            try{
                                            insertAllGpsInformation();
                                            }
                                            catch(Exception e)
                                         {
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your Net Connected or Not Login to Net"+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            Log.e("Upload Picture Error:",e.getMessage());
                                         }
                                        }


                                    });

                               }
                            };
                            mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask,180000,180000);
                        }


                        }
        }   
                }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register for the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` ([see here for details](http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/82)). Start your service on boot.

Comment: receiver = new ConnectionReceiver(); registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)); start my service like this and my <receiver android:name="ConnectionReceiver"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"> </action> <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"> </category> </intent-filter> my manifest file .But my servie is not staretd.

Answer (score 0):

You should register a BroadcastReceiver and look for the BOOT_COMPLETED Intent.

Here is link with some details: http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/starting-android-service-at-boot-time.html

Did I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

create Broadcast Receiver that with the Intent of BOOT COMPLETED Action.

please refer following links for more help :

1. http://blog.gregfiumara.com/?p=82
2. http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

You can use

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Log.i("BootReceiver :: Start Booting..");

      Intent i = new Intent(context, StartService.class);    // Start your service class
           i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
           context.startActivity(i);    
   }
   }
```

and use the broadcastreciever in androidmanifest.xml as

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.BootReceiver">
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: receiver = new ConnectionReceiver();

registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)); start my service like this and my <receiver android:name="ConnectionReceiver">
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
  </action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME">
  </category>
 </intent-filter> my manifest file .But my servie is not staretd.

Comment: where u staring the service ,maeant where u put the intent for startservice in HOME? please put the code..